# Detecting touch on button with complex shape Java Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm writing a game with java and libgdx and I need to manage clicking on some images with crazy shapes. 
Here is just quick example:
[Only red area should be clickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZiY9.png)

I always use some polynomials to approximate shape but it's very laborious and isn't perfect. Any solutions how to find if the click is in that weird area ?

Comment: You can use a bitmap image, like the one you have.

Comment: Could you expand your solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detection of touch on complex shape, like your Image specified red area.

Use [Physics Body Editor](http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/physics-body-editor/) mostly used for tracing of shape that used to create shape of physics body.

When you export, it give you .json file having no. of points as vertices of your shape. Use that vertices or deserialize into Polygon object.

After that you can check your touchX and touchY is in your specified Polygon.